# Sum of 10 Random Numbers Using WHILE Loop - Java

Tags: java

For the last five hours I've been struggling with this Java code that uses a **While** loop to add up 10 user-input numbers. I've gotten my code to work up until it's time to output the sum (which is always wrong; I usually end up getting 55).

Can someone *please* help me fix this? I feel as if it's a small error, but I can't tell where it is.

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Loops {

public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);  

 int sum = 0; 
 int counter = 0;

while (counter < 10) {
System.out.println("Please enter a number: ");
int i = input.nextInt();
counter++;

sum = sum + counter;
counter = counter + 1;
}
System.out.println("The total sum is " + sum);
}
}
```

Comment: `counter++;` and `counter = counter + 1;`? There may be one too many here...

Comment: Ok, you're summing them wrong. `sum = sum + i`, not `counter`. You also seem to be using two counter increments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has a couple of mistakes inside the `while` loop.

Firstly, on this line:

```
sum = sum + counter;
```

you're adding `counter` to the sum each time. The variable that contains the input number is `i`, you need to be adding this instead.

Secondly, you're incrementing `counter` twice each time through the loop. This means you'll only really ask the user for five numbers.

Comment: Thanks, everyone! I spent WAY more time than I should have on this for such a simple mistake. My debugger made no sense to me since I'm still new to coding.

Comment: Happy to help. If this answer or another one here solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

You need to follow the instructions, You are reading the input and then ignoring it, it says you should be summing them, not the counter.

Note: you only need to increment the counter once.

If you have spent more than 5 minutes without using your debugger most likely you have been wasting your time.